# Working Around Runtime Dependencies While Debugging In Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

When debugging an application in Visual Studio, how do you deal with design-time VS installed differences?  For example, let's say that when your program is installed it creates a file in a specific directory and then while running the application looks to read or write to that file.  How do you "simulate" the installed environment?  Another example would be a database created upon installation.  How do you imitate that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the application from your Setup/Installer so that you have sort of a production environment. Then debug the installed application. Either attach to the running application or choose the application to run in the debug settings:

[image: Start external program]